# PHP Sorting Array ASC

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to Sort the following Array but for some odd reason it doesn't seem to work

```
$sizearray = Array ( 
                       [0] => 39 
                       [1] => 40 
                       [2] => 41 
                       [3] => 42 
                       [4] => 43 
                       [5] => 44 
                       [6] => 45 
                       [7] => 39 
                       [8] => 40 
                       [9] => 41 
                       [10] => 42 
                       [11] => 43 
                       [12] => 44 
                       [13] => 45 
                       [14] => 39 
                       [15] => >40 
                       [16] => 41 
                       [17] => 42 
                       [18] => 43 
                       [19] => 44 
                       [20] => 45 
                 );


$sizearray = array_values(sort(array_unique($sizearray)));
```

And the following warnings shows up:

```
>Warning: array_values() [function.array-values]: The argument should be an array in 
>/home/starlet/public_html/productlist.php on line 349
```

Note: If i remove `sort()` function, the `array_values()` function runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `sort` is in-place and returns a boolean.

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/sort):

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

You'll probably need to do something like this:

```
$sizearray = array_unique($sizearray);
sort($sizearray);
$sizearray = array_values($sizearray);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php):

> ### Return Values
>
> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

Note how it does not say "Returns the sorted array". This is because `sort()` sorts in-place.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$fruits = array(
    "Orange1", "orange2", "Orange3", "orange20"
);
sort($fruits, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>

The above example will output:

fruits[0] = Orange1
fruits[1] = orange2
fruits[2] = Orange3
fruits[3] = orange20
```